# How do you do a BULK Export to a CSV using a SQL Server 2005 Query?

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, export, bulk

I have simple Bulk Inserts down. I am trying to take the same type of query and write to a file instead of reading from a file. The opposite of BULK Insert from a File.

If you need a scenario for the example below, I am creating a table from a text file, running a DISTINCT query to remove duplicate rows/lines and then I want to output the deduplicated result to another text file.

My simple BULK Insert query is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEMP 
(NUMBER40 VARCHAR(16), 
BIN VARCHAR(6))

BULK INSERT dbo.TEMP 
FROM 'c:\install\InputWithDupes.txt' 
WITH 
(FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NUMBER40
FROM dbo.TEMP
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\install\DeDupedOuput.txt'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ,
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

I would also like to be able to add some logic like `WHERE NUMBER40 LIKE '123%'` if possible.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use [bcp queryout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162802.aspx) ?

Comment: Those (bcp/sqlcmd) were the only solutions I found through research but I need to send the command from a web page so a query with SQL would be better.

Comment: In that it might be best to have the web page code behind handle the data returned by the sql query and export it to a csv rather than doing it in SQL

Comment: If you are using c#, use EPPlus to export data to csv/excel.  http://epplus.codeplex.com/